# Showing selection from a lapply selectInput R shiny

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, lapply

I want to show the user what they selected in a table.  I have the following:

```
   library(shiny)


ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(column(width = 4, 

                                      numericInput("assets", label = "Choose How Many Attributes to Produce in the Map:", value="1"),
                                      uiOutput("variants"),
                                      uiOutput("variants2")

)


)))

server <-shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {


  df <- iris


  output$variants <- renderUI({
    numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)
    lapply(1:(numAssets), function(i) {
      list(selectInput (paste0("choose_columns", i),
                        "Choose Attribute",
                        sort(unique(names(df)), decreasing = FALSE),
                        selected=""))

    })
  })

  output$variants2 <- renderUI({
    numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)  




    lapply(1:(numAssets), function(j) {

      var <- input[[paste0("choose_columns", j)]]

      selectInput (paste0("choose_attribute", j), 
                   paste0("Choose Attribute Value of ", var),
                   sort(unique(df[ ,var]), decreasing = FALSE),
                   selected="")
    })
  })
})



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can the user see in a table/dataframe the selection(s) from 'Choose Attribute' and 'Choose Attribute Value of Petal.Length'? I've tried something like this:

```
  output$tableofselections <- renderUI({
numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)
 for (j in 1:(numAssets)){
  x =input[[paste0("choose_columns",j)]]
}
tagList(
  helpText(paste0(x))) })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "see what they select"? The selected values/rows/columns will be highlighted?

Comment: I want a something like a table:

Atrribute(s)      Value(s)
Sepal.Width        2
Petal.Length        1.4

Comment: ... something maybe like...

  output$whatwaschoosen2<-renderTable({
    Attribute<-input$choose_columns2
    Value<-input$further
    data.frame(Attribute,Value)
  })

Comment: `RenderTable` should work fine. Did you try it?

Comment: the problem with renderTable.. is it doesn't work when i have the loop.. 

numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)
 for (j in 1:(numAssets)){
  x =input[[paste0("choose_columns",j)]]
}